# Multinomial conditional logistic regression

Tags: regression, conditional-probability, multinomial-logit

I have a dependent variable that comes with 3 categories A, B, and C, and I want to fit a multinomial logistic regression for an exposure variable, along with some confounding factors.

In order to decrease the bias, I would also like to match exposed people to non-exposed people, most likely using a propensity score.

However, I could not find any way to fit multinomial logistic regression that would be also conditional:

- in R, neither [`nnet::multinom`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nnet/versions/7.3-16/topics/multinom) not [`mlogit::mlogit()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/e1mlogit.html) provide an argument to apply the identifier
- it cannot be done using SAS's `proc logistic` (the [SAS doc](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_logistic_syntax22.htm#statug.logistic.modelstmtlink) says that "The LINK= option is not available with the STRATA statement."), but I'm not familiar with SAS so I might have missed another `proc.`

Is there a technical limitation that prevents computing a multinomial conditional logistic regression?

Otherwise, is there a software solution that would allow computing such a regression? (preferentially using R or SAS)

Comment: Are you sure that matching and conditional regression is the best approach? Have you considered (inverse) propensity weighting, so that you don't throw away so many cases as you do with matching?

Comment: @EdM That would be a nice alternative indeed. Similar studies have used matching so we wanted to use the same methodology, but you certainly have a point here and we will definitively consider it. (However, I'd still like to know if multinominal conditional logistic regressions are doable or not.)